# What is the product of the roots of a polynomial equation?

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots, products

I'm trying to solve a question that says that for the equation $z^4 + pz^3 + 54z^2 - 108z + 80 = 0$, three of the roots of the equation are $3 + i, a$ and $a^2$.

I know that for a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the product of the roots is $\frac{c}a$, but I don't know how this would apply to the polynomial equation in this question.

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @Another User! But can you answer my question?

Comment: Just use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Complex roots come in conjugate pairs so $3-i$ is also a root. That means you know all four roots.

Comment: @CyclotomicField it is true provided the coefficients are from $\mathbb{R}$. We don't know about the coefficient $p$.

Comment: Thanks guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For a cubic case if we let the roots be $a,b,c$,

$$
k\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)\left(x-c\right)\\~\\
=k\left(x\left(x-b\right)\left(x-c\right)-a\left(x-b\right)\left(x-c\right)\right)\\~\\
=k\left(x^2\left(x-c\right)-xb\left(x-c\right)-ax\left(x-c\right)+ab\left(x-c\right)\right)\\~\\
=k\left(x^3-cx^2-bx^2+bcx-ax^2+acx+abx-abc\right)\\~\\
=k\left(x^3-ax^2-bx^2-cx^2+abx+bcx+acx-abc\right)\\~\\
=kx^3-k(a+b+c)x^2+k(ab+bc+ac)x-kabc\\~\\
$$

as you can see, the last term is the product of the roots times the coefficient of the first term. This applies generally to any polynomial where if $p\left(x\right)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, the product of roots will be $$\frac{(-1)^na_0}{a_n}$$So your product of roots is $80$.

Answer (score -1):

From [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), for polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^n$ and $r_i$ are the roots,  we have $$\prod_{i=1}^nr_i = (-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n} $$

Hence the produce is $80$. Note that there is no need to compute the roots in order to obtain the product of the roots.

Comment: thanks for helping me bro!